# Find the Index of the Selected Object

Tags: c++, indexing, grouping, selecteditem, c++03

Given an object `Foo` which has the method `bool isChecked() const`. Let's say that I have `Foo foos[]`.

I am guaranteed that exactly one element of `foos` will return `true` on `isChecked()`, all others will return `false`.

I'm looking for a clever C++03 way to find the index of the `true` element. I can do this but it's pretty ugly. Does anyone have something better?

```
distance(foos, find_if(foos, foos + SIZE, mem_fun_ref(&Foo::isChecked)))
```

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 42

class Foo{
    bool checked;
public:
    Foo() : checked(false) {}
    void setChecked() { checked = true; }
    bool isChecked() const { return checked; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foos[SIZE] = {};

    foos[13].setChecked();

    cout << distance(foos, find_if(foos, foos + SIZE, mem_fun_ref(&Foo::isChecked))) << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/4g9n8e)

Comment: That's not too much code to show it directly in your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah I was going for simple elegance, but your right; now that I see it with the code in the question, it's just a clearer question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately my answer is not clever, and more importantly may not fit your use case(s). But I would make a class (or struct) which hold your Foo container and keep the index. You have to store an extra int (or whichever type you need for an index) but won't have to calculate the position of the valid object.

For instance something like that (or with whichever type of container fits your requirements or with template if you want to use it not only for Foo..):

```
class Foos {
private:
    int _index = -1;
    Foo _foos[MAXSIZE] = {};
public:
    Foos(int size, int index)
    {
      ....
    }
    int getIndex()
    {
        return _index;
    }
};

//...
//   then just call getIndex() when needed
```

Comment: Yeah that's what my current design is doing. (Well I have a `size_t index` variable that I maintain when I work on `foos`.) This may in fact be the best solution though :(

Comment: I am glad I wasn't  too far off. I was also thinking of vector or something similar so that you don't have a fixed sized, but that depends of your use case/context as well.

Comment: Yeah the size is fixed. This does have the added benefit that `Foos` could be responsible for making sure that only one item was ever checked at a time, so in the general case I like this, and I expect I'll have to accept this. It's just not the most glorious solution for me, as this is my actual issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028967/finding-a-wxmenus-selected-radio-item?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I see, so I guess your WxWidget EventHandler is updating the Foos once an event is received. I haven't dealt with UI for ages but I did remember that keeping this intermediary "kindof" status of the GUI was frustrating. My only suggestion would be to not keep a copy of the Foo in the Foos as they are already kept in the Wxwidget, something that identifies the radiobutton) so that the logic that need to know the statuses can get the information from the Foos.

Comment: Yeah, for me that's just the other `size_t index` variable I was talking about. This whole thing feels like pushing rather than driving the car though :/